# JSON root key configuration

Tags: json

{
 "name:Sagar": {
  "Subject1": "Maths",
  "Subject2": "science",
  "Subject3": "English",
  "Subject4": "French"
 }
}

how to parse this json payload ?  Normally we use "name":"Sagar" but know my query is "name:sagar" . Please help me to solve this type of JSON payload .

Comment: you can parse this as usual JSON with the difference taht now "name:sagar" is your key and the rest is your value (which itself is an dict with key-value-pairs) - to parse the "Name" you need to parse into your key after parsing the JSON

Comment: you can retrive data from index

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify the language, so here is Javascript example. The main idea is that, you parse JSON as normal and then you take the root key and explode it by ":" and then use only the value after ":"

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
for(var i in object) {
  var name = i.split(":");
  object[name[1]] = object[i];
  delete object[i];
}
```

Comment: language java - with spring mvc

Comment: so just parse it like normal JSON and then take the root key and split the string with ":" divider and you have the name in second chunk

Comment: how can i represent this "name:sagar" in Class Object Wrapping when i receive request from client

Answer (score 0):

in JSON, objects are written like :

{ "objectName" : { "first member" , "second member " , ... } }

here your object name is "name:Sagar"

perhaps you wanted to make "name:Sagar" a single value then you write :

{ "name" : "Sagar" ,
"newObjectName" : { "Subject1": "Maths", "Subject2": "science", "Subject3": "English", "Subject4": "French" } }

other solution with your own JSON, you parse and then split the "name:Sagar" with the ":" separator.

Hope that help you.

Comment: how can i represent this "name:sagar" in Class Object Wrapping when i receive request from client